# How to add second .r2 animation class to this mySlides div before it show next or previous Slides

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

Here is a Quotes slider that show next or previous quote slides with fadeInUp animation that is comes from ".r1" animation class, Okay

But Now i want that when i click on next or previous button the quotes must be not only display none but also disappear with ".r2" fadeOutUp animation class.

In simple term, When i click on next or previous button the current quote slide must be disappear with .r2 animation and then parallel to it the next quote must be appear with .r1 class animation.

How it will be possible ?

Thanks in advance. Love You to Helping buddy :)

see my all codes here:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<style>

/* animation Classes start */

.r1 {
    animation: fadeInUp 1000ms both
}


@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}


.r2 {
    animation: fadeOutUp 1000ms both
}

@keyframes fadeOutUp {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }
}

/* animation Classes End */

</style>


<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {font-style: italic;}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides r1">
  <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
  <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides r1">
  <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
  <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides r1">
  <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
  <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

i want that, When i click on next or previous button the current quote slide must be disappear with .r2 animation and then parallel to it the next quote must be appear with .r1 class animation.

Thanks in advance. Love You to Helping buddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute an animation after the first one you can use the [animationend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event).  Your code now is:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        if (slides[i].style.display == 'block') {
            slides[i].className = slides[i].className.replace("r1", "r2");
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides.r2').length == 0) {
        // first slide to fade....
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides').forEach(function(ele) {
    ele.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
        var prevEle = document.querySelector('.mySlides.r2');
        if (prevEle != null) {
            prevEle.style.display = 'none';
            prevEle.classList.remove("r2");
            prevEle.classList.add("r1");
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        }
    })
})
```

```css
/* animation Classes start */
.r1 {
    animation: fadeInUp 1000ms both
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
.r2 {
    animation: fadeOutUp 1000ms both
}
@keyframes fadeOutUp {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }
}
/* animation Classes End */
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #f1f1f1f1;
}
/* Slides */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    padding: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: white;
}
/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}
/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {font-style: italic;}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides r1">
        <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
        <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides r1">
        <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
        <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides r1">
        <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
        <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Without animationend event:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        if (slides[i].style.display == 'block') {
            slides[i].className = slides[i].className.replace("r1", "r2");
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides.r2').length == 0) {
        // first slide to fade....
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(function() {
        var prevEle = document.querySelector('.mySlides.r2');
        if (prevEle != null) {
            prevEle.style.display = 'none';
            prevEle.classList.remove("r2");
            prevEle.classList.add("r1");
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

```css
/* animation Classes start */
.r1 {
    animation: fadeInUp 1000ms both
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
.r2 {
    animation: fadeOutUp 1000ms both
}
@keyframes fadeOutUp {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }
}
/* animation Classes End */
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #f1f1f1f1;
}
/* Slides */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    padding: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: white;
}
/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}
/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {font-style: italic;}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides r1">
        <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
        <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides r1">
        <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
        <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides r1">
        <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
        <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225501/discussion-on-answer-by-gaetanom-how-to-add-second-r2-animation-class-to-this-m).